# Change of variable type after sort in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have the following code:

```
my $decoded_json = decode_json($result);
print Dumper($decoded_json);
```

And the output is this:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'searchLogMessages' => [],
      'startToken' => '',
      'documents' => [
                       {
                         'status' => 'Open',
                         'inheritedLabels' => [],
                         'aliases' => [
                                        {
                                          'precedence' => '2013-07-31T07:37:14.071Z',
                                          'id' => 'abc'
                                        }
                                      ],
                         'title' => '[DE] Add Category Specific Example Tab',
                        }
                     ],
      'totalNumberFound' => 1
    };
```

I want to access `document->aliases->id`.

```
foreach my $issue (@{$decoded_json->{documents}}) {
    my @aliases_arr = sort {$b->{precedence} cmp $a->{precedence}} $issue->{aliases};
    print ref($issue->{aliases}), "\n";    #prints "ARRAY"
    print $issue->{aliases}[0]->{id}, "\n";   #prints "abc"
    print ref($aliases_arr[0]), "\n";   #prints "ARRAY"
```

}

why is `$aliases_arr[0]` is of array type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$issue->{aliases}` isn't an array, it is an array reference. As `sort` expects a list (which here consists of a single array reference), your code doesn't work and `@aliases_arr` only contains a single array reference, which is the same as `$issue->{aliases}`.

You have to dereference it:

```
my @aliases_arr = sort { $b->{precedence} cmp $a->{precedence} } @{$issue->{aliases}};
```

Now everything should alomost work, and `print ref($aliases_arr[0])` gives `HASH`.

Comment: I also did `print ref($issue->{aliases}), "\n";` and output was `ARRAY`. Can you tell why? I have also edited the question correspondingly

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam This is because `$issue->{aliases}` is an array reference: `[...]`. Scalars values can only contain strings, numbers or references. References can also point to collection types like hashes or arrays, but scalars can't directly contain collections.